# WPF ComboBox custom Scrollbars

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, scroll

I'm looking for a resource on how to change the size (width) of the scrollbar presented by a combobox in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2008/06/styling-listbox-with-silverlight-2-beta_21.html seems to be a pretty good description for how to style the scroll bar in Silverlight.  Much of it should be workable in WPF.

Comment: The link went bad, here is an updated one:  http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2008/10/styling-listbox-in-silverlight-2.html